# What, if any, are the limitations on Samantha's powers in Bewitched?

Tags: magic, magical-theory, bewitched

Was watching the 60s series **Bewitched,** and it brought up some questions.

In the first episode, Samantha herself says she can only do "little things", which seem to consist mostly of making things levitate, limited telekinesis, turning invisible/intangible, creating localized disturbances in the immediate environment, transmutation (changing people to animals) and conjuring things out of thin air, with the biggest example being her filling up her living room with items.

Over time, though, these "little things" seem to grow and scope, to the point where teleportation, various environmental manipulations, mind control (making people do and act on things without them knowing why), dimensional tapping (trans-versing the mortal realm and others), limited control over the *Space/Time* continuum (freezing time, going back and forward), and even *Creating life out of nothing* ... or rather, giving physical form to people and animals from her imagination.

The only real "limit" ever stated in the show was a "Keyed Curse" idea... in other words, if *one* witch put a specific curse or spell on someone, even a more powerful witch *couldn't* remove i; it had to be done by the **same person,** or a specific condition had to be met (the "True Love's Kiss" restoring them, being an example.)

So, **Main Question:** In canon, were there any other stated limits or conditions under which Witches and Warlocks couldn't use their magic, or were they capable of essentially doing anything they could imagine?

What about Samantha specifically; she implied she was only a "median level" witch, so are there things *She* can't do that others can?

Answer (score 1):

The witches in Bewitched are ridiculously over powered. Samantha would wipe the floor with any magic user from pretty much any serious system whether books, movies, manga or whatever. The only "limit" she has is being unable to control her magic when ill with a "witchy" disease and not being able to undo another witch's magic (standard for all the witches in the franchise).
She is canonically less powerful than her mother Endora and is unsuccessful when she tries to curse her or send her away by magic early in the series. However other witches frequently curse Samantha, send her into the past, etc. So if a stronger witch cannot be affected by a weaker one against her will then she's far from being the most powerful witch in the story.

Comment: There are some bold assertions being made here but can you back any of them up with evidence?

Comment: Agree with everything you say. But there's  no clear delineation of "power caste" in the show, either. Maurice seems more powerful than Endora, but that varies. ?it's not _age_ that grants power, because Aunt Clara is old, but her powers are _declining._ And the High Cancel of Witches, regarded as "Supremely powerful" **wanted Sam** with them, due to her experiences, not her strength. So magic power _may_ be a result of _knowledge and skill_ more so than time. Tabitha is implied to be limited only because her dad is a mortal, but she's done things on Sam's level. So it's pretty inconsistent.

Comment: She was so limited that she didn't even notice her husband got a head transplant

Comment: @Valorum : she can re-wind time, for the whole world, for hours, at a whim (to have enough time to enjoy breakfast for instance). In DBZ the most powerful (destroy worlds at a whim) characters could only reverse time for something like three minutes. In the MCU you need the infinity gauntlet ... not convinced? Witches in Bewitched can teleport anywhere, are immortal, can resurrect the dead, can freeze time, create alternate time lines for fun, make fictional things real, grant a witch's power to a mortal, control weather, do anything they can imagine, with no power drain or fatigue ... god cla

Comment: @Gwyn - Where and when does she do these things? In which episode? And why?

Comment: @Valorum - good grief, let's see, haven't watched this in ages, but in season one around episode 9 or 10 Samantha teleports to Paris for lunch with Endora because her husband is working all the time and she's bored at home. (Also both Tabitha and Adam later pop their parents to them when they're lonely or hungry while still toddlers). Maurice first meets Darrin an episode or two later he disintigrates him and Endora reverses it - either resurrecting him or creating a new identical person or reversing his personal timeline anyway he comes back from the dead. Samantha goes back in time a number

Comment: Great, now add that evidence to your answer and this will go from being a fairly poor answer that relies on one person's assertions to being a good answer that offers specific evidence that others can check.

Comment: .... of times e.g. in season 2 sent by Endora to see if Darrin would have married her if she told him she was a witch, creating a new timeline in the process, before returning to her old timeline. Also in season 2 she's trying to write a civil war play and brings her imaginary characters to life. In season 4 aunt Clara casually summons a newspaper from the future to get the racing results. I have a suspicion the turning back time was from the recent movie as I can't remember when it happened in the series, though Endora was always freezing time for the rest of the world while casting

Comment: @Valorum : Don't know if it should really be in the answer. Didn't think it was pertinent as the question was originally about what the limitations were and how Samantha could be considered average rather than super powerful, seeing as it didn't look as if she had any limits. But sure, if that's what the site wants ...

Comment: @Gwyn These are all feats which I'm guessing your using to essentially class an "average" Witch like Sam as basically "limitless", but there _have_ been instances in the show when their powers _haven't_ worked or have had specific boundaries on them. Aside from the User-only Spell Lock, there _were_ times Sam had to go to the Council for approval, or have her Mom's help with a spell or effect, or _sickness_ affected her strength/accuracy...but there seemed to be no more "Absolute" rules. Now even adjusting for plot convenience for a given episode, isn't there _any_ other limit like Spell lock?

Comment: @Gwyn Spitballing here, friend, but just a thought.... the feats you've described were seen in _another_ nigh-all powerful being in a 60s TV show.... **Star Trek:TOS** _Trelane._ He had the ability to do basically whatever he wanted, but was subject to _higher_ beings of his same race judgement. Looking at the effects and how the hold themselves over humans...is it _possible_ that earth=bound witches are simply members of the Start Trek Q continuum,  who have yet to evolve to their full form????

Comment: @Russhiro: Q is a whole other kettle of fish. Might actually mak sense if bewitched is full of baby Q's *snigger* as to the earlier, already mentioned both the user-only spell lock and powers not working when ill. I still say those are the only hard limits. Having to get an okay from the council is about rules, not inability. And Sam being less powerful than Endora is canon.